# Cat a command to file

Tags: bash, grep

My bash script does many things, among which creating another script. I would like to have the following line to be executed from within a script. But it does not work (grep is executed instead of pasted in search.sh). What am I doing wrong?

> cat "grep --ignore-case $1 *.find" > search.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong command.

```
echo "grep --ignore-case $1 *.find" > search.sh
```

Comment: Quotes should be single?..

Answer (score 2):

Use echo instead of cat.

And because you use wildcards, maybe you want to use »'«, not »"«:

echo 'grep --ignore-case $1 *.find' >> search.sh